# Derived attribute in Django model

Tags: django, django-models

I have these two models:

```
class Product(models.Model):

    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')

    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, verbose_name=u'نام کالا')
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name=u'قیمت')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products_images', verbose_name=u'عکس')
    #score ???

    def get_score(self):
        pass


class Review(models.Model):

    product = models.ForeignKey('Product')

    rating = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(max_length=1, verbose_name=u'امتیاز')
```

How can I have a derived attribute for `Product` called score, so when I call `product.score` it calls the get_score function and returns the average score calculated from `Review` model?
For example if a product has two reviews with scores 4 and 2, I want to `product.score` returns 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you name your method `score` you could use a property:

```
@property
def score(self):
    pass
```

and this means `product.score` will return the result of that method. However this all takes place outside of Django's ORM so it wouldn't be recognized as a field on your model. Nonetheless it works in your Python code and in your templates you could use `{{ product.score }}`.

Comment: Thank you for your brief and well described answer. I'll accept that as an answer